# Protection from Evil Rain?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Evil rain tends to injure my dwarves, and in one instance, caused death. Is there a special combination of clothing I should make them wear so as to minimize the rain's effects?

Comment: At least you've got (limited) protection from sieges. I'm not sure clothing will help, you might just need to confine them underground

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wiki details on [syndromes](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Syndrome) suggest that armor doesn't protect against evil rains or evil clouds. That means that the only protection is to not be out in the rain. Build roofs on outdoor structures, when the weather permits, dig down to the cavern levels for pasture and water access, and otherwise keep all your dwarves indoors.